# Testflight application/IPA installation asking for passcode

Tags: iphone, ios, testflight

I am new to TestFlight. I built my IPA and distributed it with TestFlight. Most of my beta testers were able to install it with no issues *but* a few have reported that they are prompted with the passcode entry screen - This does not look like a 4 digit code screen that iPhone pops up for the usual security. Please provide some guidance on what is happening -

I think it has nothing to do with TF but just want to validate it.

Thanks in advance.
R.S.

Comment: What *does* the passcode entry screen look like then?

Comment: Unfortuntaely I could not upload the image as I am new to StackOverflow & it does not allow image upload from new users....will try to paste a link soon (hopefully it would work)

Comment: Ok - I think I made some progress. Found this link:
 http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/835402-what-is-my-passcode-    

But the screen my user is getting for passcode entry is different..it does not have 4 boxes for numbers but a text field with full keyboard

Answer (score 0):

TestFlight can be flakey, have him try these things: http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/867631